# Can I use Access Restrictions to only allow access from whitelisted IPs to my Azure App Service?

Tags: firewall, azure, azure-app-services

I have a public dev environment that I'm trying to lock down to just a few people. The Access Restrictions has a default Allow All rule that can't be removed.

[image]

If I try to add a blocking rule, it requires a specific IP range and doesn't appear to allow asterisks or anything. Is it possible to use this to block all IPs except a few?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default allow rule is removed once you add an IP restriction. You can add either a single IP address or an IP CIDR range, you can't use wildcards but that doesn't really make sense in this scenario.

Comment: Ah. That works perfectly. Thanks!